# AWS lambda inline editor does not save changes

Tags: aws-lambda

I tried 'hello world' program on AWS Lambda from [here](https://www.journaldev.com/29262/run-hello-world-on-aws-lambda) and it worked well

I modified the code and test event to print `event.key1` value instead of `'Hello from lambda'`.  No matter whatever I try output was same

Output is shown below

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}
```

I am not sure why code change was not reflected and unable to find relevant articles on this

Comment: How are you triggering your function? The test event is only passed to the function if you invoke your function by clicking on the "Test" button in the Lambda UI

Comment: Yes I click on Test button to invoke the function

Comment: Have you saved or deployed the updates?

Comment: I saved the text in inline editor.  I did not deploy